# Can chat depend on one user's privilege only, as chat is most useful when encountering new users?

Tags: feature-request, chat, privileges

Currently stackoverflow asks me to move the discussion to chat, but the questioner doesn't have enough points to be able to chat. It would be more useful to be able to chat with the questioner even when he has not enough rep.

Or maybe take the sum of reps or create a new privilege to initiate chat unilaterally.

Comment: This => http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/invite-low-rep-users-to-participate-in-chat