# Is there any python dedicated group under Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, languages

I am seeking a python dedicated site under Stack Exchange so that I can have discussion with experts in this area.

Is there such a site?

Comment: What do you mean by "group"? We're not really a "discussion" site. We are a Question and Answers site. Are you trying to ask where you should direct questions about Python?

Comment: For group, I mean such as 'Stack Overflow', 'Super User', 'Server Fault', ... Sorry, it seems I should say 'site'. English is not my native language.

Comment: Is there something about Stack Overflow that you're not OK with? They have thousands of questions about Python there... 793366, to be exact. It's their seventh most popular tag.

Comment: There is a Python chatroom as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I am seeking a python dedicated site under Stack Exchange

Stack Overflow is there but it is not specific for python. But python is on topic there.

> so that I can have discussion with experts in this area.

There is no discussion site in Stack Exchange to discus about a specific programming technology.

Meta is the site to discuss about the site and the MSE is the place to discuss about the software that powers Stack Exchange sites.

If you want to discuss about a specific technology, you can do it in **Chat**.

You need at least 20 reputation to participate in chat or you should be allowed to access to chat by the Mod.

A quick search gave me this room for python.

[Python Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)

But please read their [FAQ](https://sopython.com/pages/chatroom) before starting a discussion.

---

<sup>*Thanks @Jonrsharpe for the faq link*</sup>

Comment: The chat FAQ is here: https://sopython.com/pages/chatroom

Comment: Thanks for the link @jonrsharpe I edited the answer to include it

Comment: I'm not aware of any option I have as an RO to grant users without at least 20 rep to grant write access. It is a known [Feature Request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/invite-low-rep-users-to-participate-in-chat) but up to today only moderators can invite < 20 rep users into a chatroom.

Comment: only mods? I thought the privilege can be given by RO. thanks for the info rene

Comment: A Discus is something you throw on a sports field. I've fixed your post :)