Futility of keeping the rules around the question ban secret
The community wiki What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"? says:

To avoid bypassing the filter, its internal rules are a secret, but it is partly based on downvotes cast by other members of the communities.

How does keeping the rules secret prevent bypassing the filter; how is bypassing actually defined (what is considered bypassing the filter)?

Clearly it has not been futile since the details have not come out.

@JonCuster Supposedly secrecy is not an end in itself. Something is futile if it is incapable/unsuitable of serving its purpose (allegedly teaching people how to ask good questions). Since the question can only bring forth secrecy (maybe secrecy pursue as an end in itself) and frustration that is why I called it futile.

The only fun game of Whac-a-Mole is the actual game. Everything else is awful.

A typical Whac-A-Mole machine consists of a waist-level cabinet with a play area and display screen, and a large, soft mallet. Five to eight holes in the play area top are filled with small, plastic, cartoonish moles, or other characters, which pop up at random. Points are scored by, as the name suggests, whacking each mole as it appears. The faster the reaction, the higher the score.
[...]
The term "whac-a-mole" (or "whack-a-mole") is often used colloquially to refer to a situation characterized by a series of futile, Sisyphean tasks, where the successful completion of one just yields another popping up elsewhere.
From Wikipedia

The stated goal of the ban is to encourage people to learn how to form good questions by figuring out how to improve the ones that didn't meet site guidelines. The algorithm being public could make it less likely to achieve these goals.
Consider - if it's easier to get out of a ban by gaming the system than by learning how to ask good questions, it seems likely people will do that. Humans like shortcuts, "hacks", "cheese". The ban would be easier to circumvent, could lead to fraud, and require more manual moderation. To address this, the company would likely have to change the rules for question bans frequently, probably eventually ending up with them being secret again.
Also, while it's not something I'm comfortable thinking about, the algorithm for the ban being public could actually lead to more people being banned and make it harder for them to get unbanned if it leads to changes in how people vote. Personally, it makes me vote - particularly down - less often and I would hope it would lead to others doing the same but I can understand why it might lead some people to vote down more.
As far as I'm concerned, this is the answer to your question. The remaining sections below are designed to give context and address comments from the OP on other answers. Oh, and a small bit of opining about the q-ban.

There are actually more tools for limiting questions than most people realize. While there is the outright question ban - the six month prohibition from asking new questions unless existing ones are improved - there are also "rolling rate limits" designed to prevent users from getting banned without being aware of the potential risks of posting many "low quality" questions. There are also rate limits for very new users, to prevent them from asking multiple questions in a very short time.
In general, these systems should only impact users who are really failing and have repeatedly shown they can not create content that meets the site's quality standards. For the early years of their existence, I'd say that was probably the case. Unfortunately, these tools have been largely unchanged since they were created and something that worked when a site was only three years old isn't optimal when it's 15.
Problems with the q-ban system today
Honestly, someday I hope that they'll replace the question ban system so that they can publicize the algorithm for it. Explaining why it has to be secret likely wouldn't be necessary. As I mentioned, that obscurity has meant that it hasn't needed to be changed in over a decade... though it definitely should have changed.
While I won't go into specifics of the ban, here are some things about Stack Overflow that likely contribute to why the q-ban needs to be at least revamped, if not replaced:

The site is now 15 years old and some users have been banned for years. Time doesn't heal these wounds. This is why fixing bad questions is paramount. It's also why I specifically worked to make sure users could see all of their deleted posts.
It's difficult for many users to find the existing Q&A they need, so people ask questions they should have found through search.
Explanations of how to ask a question well are easy to miss, ineffective, or absent.
Voting behavior has changed a lot - both when people vote and what percentage of users can/do vote.

In addition, lots of questions probably aren't worth the effort to fix, leaving banned users with a permanent weight on their shoulders. This includes questions that belong on other sites, are duplicates, or are out of scope entirely.
Helping users ask better questions
In the comments, you (the OP) seem to share an understandable confusion about how question quality is defined, how users are educated, and why they're "treated like criminals". So let's talk about those...
Question quality is generally defined through UI guidance, site specific resources, and votes. A question that gets downvoted and/or closed (on a main site) is generally considered "low quality" as far as the software is concerned.
Every site on the network has its own expectations for question quality, though most follow a similar framework. This information is available on the question asking page, which sites are able to customize if they wish. There are also links to help center articles about what is in and out of scope for the site and some general tips for how to ask a question well.
Unfortunately, many people overestimate their ability to ask good questions, so they don't take advantage of the guidance given by the platform. When that happens, it's more likely that curator/reviewer intervention will be necessary. Many users on each site give feedback or edit questions that need improvement. They vote on questions to indicate quality and vote to close questions that fail to meet site standards.
When questions are closed, askers are given general guidance about how to fix questions closed depending on the reason reviewers indicated for the closure. How useful this is can be dependent on the site and what the question was.
The thing is, the company has done little to ease the burden of the users doing much of the curation and sometimes makes it worse. While everyone should be able to ask a question, that doesn't mean it needs to be so easy. Little is done to orient users to how Q&A works on Stack Exchange and how it differs from other platforms they may be familiar with. The core users have been vocal about needing better onboarding for over a decade but little has been done.
If it's not obvious - most of what you're frustrated about isn't something the users can change, so we're stuck with the system as it is, beholden to the company's willingness to do anything to address its shortcomings.
Alternatives
While there's likely still room for a very extreme question ban for users who have shown no improvement whatsoever, there should be a lot more support built into the platform to prevent that from happening. The most important note, though - any alternatives should have the equal goal of lightening the load for the core users.
The question asking workflow really needs to be revamped in a way that gives sites more direct control of the process and more options for customization. Users should be introduced to what expectations there are and should be warned that asking is harder than they think. Search should be part of asking a question. The question asking UI should be smart, able to warn askers if the question seems out of scope, incomplete, or likely to be considered low quality - and should be able to direct users to site-specific meta or help-center content for more information.
Questions that make it through that process should likely be put through something like Staging Ground if they can get it to scale. It could prevent publication of questions from users whose question history shows they're struggling meet certain metrics unless the question has been approved by reviewers.
There are many incremental improvements that could be made. While there have been some attempts to revamp question asking and reviewing, they don't seem particularly effective and often end up abandoned in an MVP state rather than being enhanced.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Making the Q-ban rules public wouldn't benefit sincere askers, but it would make it easy for trolls and spammers to post low-quality questions.
Sincere askers don't need to know the details of the Q-ban filter, they just need to focus on creating a useful question. But making the filter details public would assist malicious and lazy askers in flooding the site with undesirable content.
We already provide guidance for the sincere askers, in the form of Help pages, eg
Meta Stack Exchange > Help center / Asking. We expect new members to take the Help Tour, and to spend a little bit of time reading existing questions and answers, so that they get a feel for site culture, and a sense of what kinds of questions do well here, and what kinds tend to get closed or downvoted.
Admittedly, the Help center pages were originally composed in the early days of Stack Overflow, and although they have been revised in the subsequent years, many of those pages still retain a Stack Overflow focus. However, they're still a reasonable introduction to site culture, IMHO.
Unfortunately, we still get a significant percentage of questions from people who appear to be oblivious to the site culture, and who haven't taken the Tour. They treat the site as a help desk, and don't realise that we're trying to create a repository of knowledge in Q&A form. We can't force them to learn how to use the site the way the community wants, but we still need to limit the unwanted content they generate, hence the question and answer bans.

zcoop98 mentions in comments that some sincere askers get caught in Q-bans, and the current system makes it hard for them to get unbanned. That's certainly true. I don't think it's possible to totally prevent that, but it could be reduced by improved site Help documentation and on-boarding, and initiatives like the Staging Ground which started recently on Stack Overflow. Catija's comments and answer on this page have excellent information on these topics. On a related note, many new members don't realise that deleting their poorly-received question does not help them avoid a Q-ban, and in fact may accelerate the ban. IMHO, the Help documentation should make that point obvious.
In my experience, in chat rooms and site metas, almost all of the sincere askers caught in a Q-ban do not seek assistance regarding the ban when they get ban warnings. They only complain after they get banned. They may not even mention the ban. They simply bring their question to chat (or even meta), hoping to get an answer.
In some cases, these askers don't have great communication skills. They don't present their question in a clear methodical way, and they have difficulties digesting the feedback they receive. It's frustrating when you virtually need to interrogate someone in order to figure out how to help them. ;)
Many of us are happy to assist people in clarifying and streamlining their question, but there are limits. If a base level of communication cannot be established, it's difficult to make progress, no matter how well-intentioned both parties are. If someone doesn't have that base level of communication skill, they are unlikely to make useful contributions to a Stack Exchange site. IMHO.

Twice "it would make it easy for trolls and spammers to post low-quality questions" and "making the filter details public would assist malicious and lazy askers in flooding the site with undesirable content" you affirmed what I asked. Basically I asked "How" and you answered "Yes".  Someone calls them useful and someone else calls them interesting. The crux is that was is useful (or interesting) is subjective. The help center is useless unless it is what actually matters.

https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10120/do-questions-need-to-be-about-design-and-or-specific-problem-solving/10121?noredirect=1#comment21923_10121 "You can lead a horse to water but you can't make it drink" similarly "We can't force them to learn how to use the site the way the community wants but we could at least have all the relevant information (in a transparent, predictable, understanable maybe listed format) in the help center." People may have well taken the tour, appreciate that SE is a repository of knowledge but may still trigger the ban.

It's probably worth pointing out that, while it's quite attractive and convenient to imagine that the Q-ban affects only "malicious and lazy askers", reality is almost assuredly far more nuanced. I think it's fair to acknowledge that the current iteration of the Q-ban is exceedingly difficult to get out from under, and that if a sincere asker does get caught up in it, the site stacks the deck against them in a way that makes them unlikely to succeed, and gives them little incentive to do so. It's not a great state of affairs overall, IMO, and the secrecy does not make any of that better.

@zcoop98 True - though I disagree that the secrecy is a compounding factor. While all of the answers (including mine) talk about askers taking advantage of it to get themselves unbanned, the reality is, knowing what causes a ban could actually impact how people vote, leading to the possibility of frustrated voters working to get someone banned intentionally. Personally, knowing how the ban works generally leads me to avoid downvoting. While I think that others might do the same, I worry that it might exacerbate downvoting.

@PM2Ring You assume that everyone receives feedback. Many doesn't mean all. People are free to vote without giving feedback.

@George I realise that not everyone receives helpful feedback. But I wasn't just talking about comments on questions. I was also talking about the people who bring their questions to chat rooms.

@PM2Ring Unless it is not everyone that can't be any excuse. "Sincere askers don't need to know the details of the Q-ban filter, they just need to focus on creating a useful question." We aren't even allowing them to "create a useful question". Not only is that poorly defined but we are considering they get feedback when in fact they don't. How exactly would I bring my question to a chat room (that is shifting the burden to them while not even allowing them to plan ahead)?

"Unless it is not everyone that can't be any excuse. " Sorry, @George, I don't know what that's supposed to mean. "How exactly would I bring my question to a chat room?" The chat networks aren't well-advertised, and you do need a little bit of rep to post in them, but there's a link (or 2) to Chat on every question page, and plenty of people somehow manage to find the chat rooms, eg https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar

@PM2Ring New users need this "guidance" the most but you need some reputation for that. That is ridiculous.

@George There have been several requests over the years to permit high rep users to invite low rep users to chat, eg https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100291/334566 & links therein...

@PM2Ring So they don't have much agency, say there. They are at the mercy of high rep users (supposedly high rep users already know "how to ask good questions" and don't need the help but the ones that need it depend on good will)....................

"Bypassing the filter" means figuring out a way to post low-quality content without the the question ban getting tripped.
You can think of this as an example of security through obscurity, I suppose. If the exact thresholds for a question ban were made public, it might be possible to find those numbers, then continue writing bad questions in a way such that you just barely stay under them. By keeping those numbers a secret, we introduce some uncertainty into the system, which makes that harder to do.
The Stack Exchange network makes use of this strategy in other places, too. Stack Overflow, for example, has chosen not to disclose its exact generative AI detection procedures, which serves a similar function. Since users don't know exactly what will get marked as Gen AI, the safest bet is to not mess with it at all.

Comments are now taking place in chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments.

Bypass the filter would mean finding a way to continue to ask bad question whilst never hitting the q-ban.
For example, if users know that, in the span of 1 month, 5 badly received questions will get me a q-ban, users could just ask 4 badly received questions and keep doing so each and every month (made up random numbers here btw).

I am not sure I am clear on "finding a way to continue to ask bad question whilst never hitting the q-ban" isn't that circular reasoning (we are basically making it a premise that they ask bad questions and want them banned) ? How is a badly received question even defined? If we aren't fine with someone asking 4 badly received questions (followed the random numbers your made up) why is that allowed (just kept secret)? Why can't we figure out what we actually want to allow and make it public? Isn't transparence and predictability a good thing? Shouldn't a user be able to adjust their behavior?

@GeorgeNtoulos users are warned that they are reaching the threshold of being banned, and advised to adjust their behavior.

@fyrepenguin The warning is incabable of producing the desired result of allowing them to adjust their behavior. They are as "capable" to adjust their behavior as everyone is. They are not given the ability to adjust their behavior (that would be asking 4 badly received questions per month). But the focus wasn't the last part. Let me repost it.

@fyrepenguin I am not sure I am clear on "finding a way to continue to ask bad question whilst never hitting the q-ban" isn't that circular reasoning (we are basically making it a premise that they ask bad questions and want them banned) ? How is a badly received question even defined? If we aren't fine with someone asking 4 badly received questions (followed the random numbers your made up) why is that allowed (just kept secret)? Why can't we figure out what we actually want to allow and make it public? The chances of someone asking "4 badly received" every month questions are non trivial.

@fyrepenguin not always

@GeorgeNtoulos We do make what we want public; it's on each site's Help Center page and FAQ. But not everyone reads those; q-bans are our way of filtering out some of the posts from people who don't, as well as encouraging to give those resources a once-over. And the threshold is much higher than you seem to be suggesting.

@GeorgeNtoulos I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say "why is that allowed". Why is what allowed? What should any society do if members continue to break rules, even after being warned? Even if it's accidental or they're incapable of changing, you don't let people continue to cause problems. Even if it's not against the law, people who don't learn social norms will frequently find themselves excluded from social situations - and last I checked, those "rules" are even less defined than what makes a good question.

Regarding circular reasoning - it's not. I don't think anyone wants to ask "bad" questions. I do believe people want to retain the ability to ask questions. If it's public knowledge that asking five poorly-received questions in a month will lead to a six-month ban from asking, someone who has asked four poorly-received questions in a month will likely hold off on asking a fifth question until the month is over. It's risk aversion. The risk of losing the privilege is high, but it's easily avoided by simply not asking, so they don't. It's not even nefarious. Just smart gamesmanship.

@Catija Starship made the assumption (for the sake of illustration) that there is a limit of 5 questions (badly received) per month. My question was why is asking 4 badly received (which is not even defined) questions allowed unless we are actually fine with this. The member doesn't even know the rules. Shame on the "society" that the rules were broken. The society is to blame that the problems were caused in the first place when the rules aren't known.

@Anerdw Starship gave the example.  For example, if users know that, in the span of 1 month, 5 badly received questions will get me a q-ban, users could just ask 4 badly received questions and keep doing so each and every month (made up random numbers here btw). I simply followed

@Catija "It's risk aversion. The risk of losing the privilege is high, but it's easily avoided by simply not asking, so they don't. It's not even nefarious. Just smart gamesmanship." Why is that bad? Why is it even considered "gamesmanship"? The risk (to the society) of someone asking 4 badly received questions, accidentally, without even knowing the rules is non trivial. Why is asking 4 badly received questions allowed when it is considered harmful to the society?

@GeorgeNtoulos It's not bad. Someone who clearly shows they can't ask a good question should stop posting questions until they understand how to do it well. If they did, the q-ban wouldn't be necessary. The fact is, people frequently feel they need to continue to ask questions, despite being told their questions can not be answered as written, are out of scope, or have other issues. As such, the system must stop them since they can not stop themselves. Otherwise, the users who have to moderate those questions through voting and closing will never have a way to get the questions to stop.

@Catija It's not bad? What is the referent of the pronoun? Asking 4 badly received question each month? If that is not bad there is no problem letting people do that knowingly (not only accidentaly). Someone may "show" they can't ask a good question because the users are human https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402978/how-do-questions-migrated-back-count no feedback is given when voters don't care about the specifc close reason (it's just the question needs to be closed). It is not about them understanding how to do well when we speak of culture and interesting questions it is arbitrary.

@GeorgeNtoulos It's not bad for someone who has asked four "bad" questions to stop asking questions for a while. While you're correct that it was unclear in isolation, I would think the remainder of my comment would have made it abundantly clear that I was referring to users' ability to stop asking questions, since I stated it several times. I'm not sure what that linked question has to do with anything... other than making it clear that community members here are just generally getting tired with your questions and would like you to stop asking them If only there were a system to prevent you.

@Catija In the scenario they accidentally/inadvertedly "bypassed" the question ban because the algorithm was set at 5 (the assumption/premise of keeping the algorithm secret is that someone will ask 4 questions to avoid the ban so might with a non-trivial chance keep doing it by accident every month). So if asking 4 questions is bad lets lower the number instead of keeping at 5 if asking 4 questions is okay there is no problem making it public.

@Catija I am following the example set by Starship https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/402969/563808

@GeorgeNtoulos I mean... the q-ban is intended to be a last resort for users who aren't improving to lighten the burden on community members. While I'm sure it doesn't feel that way if you're in the situation, the core belief in SE moderation is that people can improve and their past mistakes shouldn't be held against them. People are allowed a few chances to fail because it can be difficult when starting out and the community is here to help guide them. Only after several failures are they blocked - temporarily. They still have a new chance every six months to show they've learned.

@GeorgeNtoulos I would be really really surprised if any of our mod are q-banned. If they are then likely they don't ask very often and only asked a few bad questions when they were new. And I think that who is popular and interesting is much more subjective then voting...

@Starship It is not about a question ban. Their mistake was a wrongful migration for example. https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10120/do-questions-need-to-be-about-design-and-or-specific-problem-solving?noredirect=1#comment21923_10121. "And what it really boils down to isn't if the question is on-topic/off-topic but just if people visiting the site will find it interesting" interesting was determining the noun question, interesting content. People don't care if the question is on-topic but if it is interesting (that is what matters to them).

@Starship It doesn't seem that the subjectivity of voting is any different from the subjectivity of what question is interesting or not.
